# Escape a period properly in snakemake expand function

Tags: python, regex, escaping, python-re, snakemake

I am writing a snakemake pipeline where I download various files whose filenames contain many periods, and I am having a devil of a time getting it to properly understand the file names.  I have essentially two rules, a download rule and a target rule.  Here they are simplified below.

```
rule download_files_from_s3:
    input:
        some input
    params:
        some params
    output:
        expand("destinationDir/{{sampleName}}\.{{suffix}}")
    shell:
        shell:
        "aws s3 cp input destinationDir"

rule targets:
    input:
        expand("destinationDir/{sampleName}\.{suffix}", sampleName=sampleNames)
```

In this formulation snakemake compiles successfully, and properly downloads the files from s3 to where I want them.  However, it is unable to find them and "says waiting at most 5 seconds for missing files".  I can see when I run the snakemake in dry run mode, the snakemake expects files of the form "destinationDir/sampleName\.suffix" when in reality they exist without a backslash: "destinationDir/sampleName.suffix". My first though was to ditch the backslash, changing my rules to the form:

```
expand("destinationDir/{sampleName}.{suffix}", sampleName=sampleNames)
```

This however creates an overly greedy regular expression.  My value for suffix should be ".params.txt".  When I run the no backslash version snakemake evaluates the wildcard **sampleName** as "sampleName.params" and the wildcard **suffix** as "txt". How ought I to best go about this either by forcing the regular expression matching in expand to behave or to have snakemake properly interpret the '' character?  My efforts so far haven't been successful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know snakemake, but reading their docs mentions that you can avoid ambiguity by providing the regex in your wildcards:

```
{wildcard,regex}
```

Eg:

```
{sampleName,[^.]+}
```

To quote the docs:

> [...]
>
> Multiple wildcards in one filename can cause ambiguity. Consider the pattern `{dataset}.{group}.txt` and assume that a file `101.B.normal.txt` is available. It is not clear whether `dataset=101.B` and `group=normal` or `dataset=101` and `group=B.normal` in this case.
>
> Hence wildcards can be constrained to given regular expressions. Here we could restrict the wildcard `dataset` to consist of digits only using `\d+` as the corresponding regular expression. With Snakemake 3.8.0, there are three ways to constrain wildcards. First, a wildcard can be constrained within the file pattern, by appending a regular expression separated by a comma:
>
> ```
> output: "{dataset,\d+}.{group}.txt"
> ```
>
> [...]

https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#wildcards

Also note that `{{wildcard}}` will "mask" the wildcard, as mentioned in the `expand` section of the docs:

> You can also mask a wildcard expression in expand such that it will be kept, e.g.
>
> ```
> expand("{{dataset}}/a.{ext}", ext=FORMATS)
> ```

https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#the-expand-function

I'm not sure how I should understand "mask" but reading the aside note at the top leads me to thing it's a way to escape the special meaning of `{` and use the string literal `{wildcard}`.

> Note that any placeholders in the shell command (like `{input}`) are always evaluated and replaced when the corresponding job is executed, even if they are occuring inside a comment. To avoid evaluation and replacement, you have to mask the braces by doubling them, i.e. `{{input}}`.

https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you don't need to escape the period, the string in `expand` isn't a regex.

If your value for the suffix always is "params.txt", a simple solution would be to specify that:

```
expand("destinationDir/{sampleName}.params.txt", sampleName=sampleNames)
```

If the suffix is variable but you want to constrain it somehow, according to the latest documentation single brackets around the suffix and setting `allow_missing` should work to preserve `suffix` as a wildcard, and you should be able to (as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69109965/15704972)) use wildcard constraints to specify the potential suffixes. Assuming that your suffix pattern is ".SOMETHING.txt":

```
rule targets:
    wildcard_constraints: 
        suffix = "\.[a-zA-Z]+\.txt"
    input:
        expand("destinationDir/{sampleName}.{suffix}", sampleName=sampleNames, allow_missing=True)
```

(Wrapping `suffix` in double brackets instead would also be a way of preserving it as the wildcard `{suffix}` rather than trying to expand it - your output in `download_files_from_s3`, as it's written now, also simplifies to

```
output: "destinationDir/{sampleName}.{suffix}"
```

where you once again can have wildcard constraints if needed. In fact, given the issue with the file names probably will continue through your workflow, you may want to set wildcard constraints globally by adding

```
wildcard_constraints:
    suffix = "\.[a-zA-Z]+\.txt"
```

to your snakefile before defining any rules.)